# error 1452 when trying to paste in values

Tags: sql

when i try enter the last part of code i get the error message "error code : 1452 cannot add or update a child row a foreign key constraint fails"

```
CREATE TABLE products (

    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar (30),
    price decimal(3,2),
    coffee_origin varchar (30)
);

CREATE TABLE customers (


    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(30),
    last_name VARCHAR (30),
    gender ENUM ('M','F'),
    phone_number VARCHAR(11)
    );

CREATE TABLE orders(

    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id INT,
    customer_id INT,
    order_time DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id)
);

INSERT INTO orders (product_id,customer_id,order_time) VALUES (1,1,'2017-01-01 08-02-11');
```

Comment: Hi enz, Just for background: Is there a row in your `products` table with an `id` of `1` and a row in your `customers` table with an `id` of `1`? Also, would it be possible to add the type of SQL database you are using for this to your question?

Comment: ahh there null, how do i assign value of 1?

Comment: Hi enz, I would try `insert`ing rows to your `products` table and `customers` table first (if there aren't any rows with an `id` of `1` in them), and then your `insert` to the `orders` table might more likely be able to run (though I can't promise that). If you insert new rows into your `products` and `customers` tables and they show a different `id` than `1`, I would use whatever `id`s they are showing you for your `orders` row (unless you really have to use `1`s for this project).

Comment: How are you going to learn if you have others do it for you instead of working it out yourself?

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to insert your values into the `orders` table, I think you might need to add rows to your `products` and `customers` tables.

Here are possible examples of how you could add rows to your `products` and `customers` tables:

```
insert into products (name, price, coffee_origin) values ('Dark Blend', 4.99, 'Brazil');

insert into customers (first_name, last_name, gender, phone_number) values ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'M', '123-456-7890');
```

Then, you can find the `id` values that you might need to use for your final `insert` action by running the following queries:

```
select id from products where name = 'Dark Blend';

select id from customers where phone_number = '123-456-7890';
```

Finally, you can try running your `insert` action again, but this time using the `id` values from the queries above this; maybe like this, if you get back `1` for the `id`s of each of those queries above:

```
insert into orders (product_id, customer_id, order_time) values (1, 1, '2021-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Comment: Hi @enz, Glad to hear that it's working! There can be a lot to learn when it comes to SQL, but I hope this is helpful with getting started. Hope you have a nice day!